# is there an easy way to import a black-on-white color scheme in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Visual Studio has a way to import, export your color settings.

Does Eclipse have something similar?

I'm looking for the "perfect" color scheme in Eclipse that's easiest on the eyes.  For me, that simply means a black background (so I'm not staring into a bright light bulb all day).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to change all the colors from the preferences, and then save these so they can be reused by others eclipse sessions (or in other workspaces).

[image: Afae window]

So a good start is to go to **`preferences->Editors->Text Editors`**.

Then go towards the bottom half and you should see "`Appearance color options`", select "`Background`", uncheck "`System Default`" and you can pick the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find a user, who uses the color schema you want to have. He can export his preferences into a file. This file you can import into your workspace.

When you dont find this person, you have to create it by your own like VonC describes.